# Can we export data from salesforce wave analytics dataset using wave REST API?

Tags: rest-api, einstein-analytics

I am trying to get all the records of salesforce wave analytics dataset object but i don't want to user GET API available for it. Is there any other way to retrieve all datasets other than regular GET API?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a close look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_resources_dataset_id.htm), the supported methods are listed.

> Dataset Resource
>
> HTTP Methods:
>
> GET

You can check the Wave REST API Reference Resources overview [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_rest_resources_overview.htm)

Comment: So how can i get all datasets with its fields/records and their values using a single call?

Answer (score 0):

Analytics allows exporting data. Please refer this link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_setup_download_enable.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

There is a ConnectAPI available that allows you to query datasets. It would work something like this. It returns a JSON with the results that needs to be processed.

```
String query = Wave.QueryBuilder.loadByDeveloperName(datasetName).foreach(fields).build('q');
ConnectApi.LiteralJson result = ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(query );
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sdk.meta/bi_dev_guide_sdk/bi_sdk_apex_examples.htm